# python matplotlib mplot3d double z axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

Is it possible to make a 3d plot using matplotlib `mplot3d` with 2 vertical z axis? One on the left one on the right side of the plot.

My plot looks like this one at the moment:

[image]